# Bootsrap table breaks word in the row

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have a simple bootstrap invoice template. I show you on the photo below, that whats my problem whit the table.

[image: Photo here]

If i open the site on a mobile or small device, the content in the cell will break, but i think, there is enough space for also a long content...

```
<table class="table table-bordered">
                                    <thead>
                                        <tr>
                                            <th class="per70 text-left">Megnevezés</th>
                                            <th class="per5 text-center">Mennyiség</th>
                                            <th class="per25 text-center">Egységár</th>
                                            <th class="per25 text-center">Bruttó érték</th>
                                        </tr>
                                    </thead>
                                    <tbody>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>Gigabyte H370 AORUS GAMING 3 WIFI alaplap</td>
                                            <td class="text-center">1 db</td>
                                            <td class="text-center">75.990 Ft,-</td>
                                            <td class="text-center">75.990 Ft,-</td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>Gigabyte GeForce GTX 1660 Ti 6GB AORUS GDDR6 videokártya /GV-N166TAORUS-6GD/</td>
                                            <td class="text-center">1 db</td>
                                            <td class="text-center">166.990 Ft,-</td>
                                            <td class="text-center">166.990 Ft,-</td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>500GB Samsung 860 EVO SSD meghajtó (MZ-76E500B/EU)</td>
                                            <td class="text-center">2 db</td>
                                            <td class="text-center">25.990 Ft,-</td>
                                            <td class="text-center">59.452 Ft,-</td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </tbody>
                                    <tfoot>
                                        <tr>
                                            <th colspan="3" class="text-right">Termékek ára</th>
                                            <th class="text-center">339 470 Ft,-</th>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <th colspan="3" class="text-right">Házhozszállítás</th>
                                            <th class="text-center">990 Ft,-</th>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <th colspan="3" class="text-right">Utánvét</th>
                                            <th class="text-center">190 Ft,-</th>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <th colspan="3" class="text-right">Fizetendő, bruttó végösszeg</th>
                                            <th class="text-center">495 290 Ft,-</th>
                                        </tr>
                                    </tfoot>
                                </table>
```

Comment: Have you tried adding the "text-nowrap" class ? Maybe it solves your problem

Comment: To the cells, or to the row?

Comment: To the cells <th class="text-center text-nowrap">495 290 Ft,-</th>